# Add multiple entries from within a program to an SQLite3 database with HDBC / Haskell

Tags: database, haskell, sqlite, hdbc

I'm trying to use Database.HDBC and Database.HDBC.Sqlite3.

To add tables to an SQLite3 database, this is the kind of command I'd enter into GHCI:

```
run conn "CREATE TABLE table1 (a INTEGER)" []
```

I'd like to now use a list of strings to add table names to a database from within my program.

This is the variable I'm working with:

```
tables = ["CREATE TABLE t1 (a INTEGER)","CREATE TABLE t2 (a INTEGER)",..]
```

tables is passed to a function I made called addTables:

```
addTables xs = [ run conn x [] | x <- xs ]
```

But my addTables function returns this error:

```
<interactive>:199:1:
    No instance for (Show (IO Integer))
      arising from a use of `print'
    Possible fix: add an instance declaration for (Show (IO Integer))
    In a stmt of an interactive GHCi command: print it
```

I suspect Haskell doesn't like list comprehensions that don't print anything?

Any help or suggestions would be greately appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, the problem is that `IO` actions can't be printed. See, you've only constructed a list of actions, rather than running them.

Try this instead:

```
addTables xs = sequence [run conn x [] | x <- xs]
```

or, equivalently:

```
addTables xs = mapM (\x -> run conn x []) xs
```

If you don't care about the results, `mapM_` is slightly more efficient.

Comment: It looks like I should spend more time researching the map functions. I've been trying to do everything with list comprehensions. Thank you for your time and help.